# string Iterator not dereferencable c++ issue

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, iterator

I must be missing something simple... However it is giving this error on the line where myDrawing is declared. Thanks for any help!

```
void buff::readFile()
{
     ifstream myDrawing("SavedDrawing.txt");
     file = "";
     char temp;
     int i = 0;
     if (myDrawing.is_open())
     {
         while(myDrawing.eof() == false)
         {
              myDrawing >> temp;
              file.push_back(temp);
         };
         myDrawing.close();
         load();
         return;
     }
     else{return;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe:

```
void buff::readFile() {
    ifstream myDrawing("SavedDrawing.txt", ifstream::in);
    char temp;
    while (myDrawing.good()) {
        cout << (char) myDrawing.get();
    }
    myDrawing.close();
    load();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like you forgot to include <iostream> or <fstream> which is confusing the compiler.

If that doesn't work, try changing "ifstream" to "std::ifstream" and see if you get a better error message.